# API login from android app using laravel 5.3 passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

For two days I am digging google but could not find the starting thread for my problem, now I am out of option. Please help me with some direction/howTo

I have a web application running built with laravel 5.3, I have installed passport as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/passport#installation) . if I go `/home` its showing perfectly.

[image: Home page]

Now I have to make an android app from which

1. An already existing user of web app can login
2. get all the task list of that user `TaskModel (ons_tasks(id, title, description))`

routes related only

in web.php

```
Auth::routes();
```

in api.php

```
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
})->middleware('auth:api');


Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {

    Route::get('/test', function (Request $request) {
        return response()->json(['name' => 'test']);
    });

    Route::get('/task/list', function (Request $request) {        
        $list = \App\Model\TaskModel::all();
        return response()->json($list);
    });

});
```

**To login :** if I send post request `/login` with email & password get the `TokenMismatchException` error but *Where do I obtain a token for
android app in mobile?* Do I need the `Auth::routes()` in the api too?
if then what else Do I need to just login and get a token so later I
can send it for getting the task lists.

Secondly,

If I go to  `/api/test` it redirects me to `/home` page without
showing any error !!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi did you solve this?

Answer (score 8):

## To authenticate with your Passport-enabled API

You'll need to use the Password Grant Client in this situation, see [this section of Passport's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#password-grant-tokens).

Once you've generated a Password Grant Client, using:

```
 php artisan passport:client --password
```

You will need to request an access token from your application, and send it with your subsequent requests, in order to access the protected auth:api middleware routes.

To get an access token, send a request to your app's `/oauth/token` route (this is a PHP implementation obviously, ensure you are correctly formatting below request in your Java implementation):

```
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $http->post('http://your-app.com/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => '<client id returned from the artisan command above>',
    '    client_secret' => '<secret returned from artisan command above>',
        'username' => 'taylor@laravel.com',
        'password' => 'my-password',
        'scope' => '',
    ],
]);

return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

Ensure you add the `client_secret` and `client_id` that was returned from the artisan call above, and ensure `username` and `password` references a valid user in your database.

If everything is fine here, you should receive an `access_token` and `refresh_token` in the response. The `access_token` is what you need to authenticate using the `auth:api` guard. To correctly pass this back to your api, you will need to send your subsequent requests with the headers `Authorization: Bearer <your accessToken>` and `Accept: application/json`

For example, to access your "test" route:

```
$response = $client->request('GET', '/api/test', [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '. <accessToken from /oauth/token call>,
    ],
]);
```

If you've set these correctly, you should see a JSON response with the array you have specified.

## Why is /api/test redirecting me with no error?

You are requesting a route with the `auth:api` middleware. This will redirect you as you have not specified the correct headers as described above, this is expected behavior.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am starting to read about Laravel Passport. If Password Grant Tokens is not used, authorization tokens are not issued? (but rather a session is created in another Laravel project?) 

From Laravel's documentation ```This allows you to issue access tokens securely to your first-party clients without requiring your users to go through the entire OAuth2 authorization code redirect flow.``` What does this mean?